# What is the reason for different engine configurations seen on Solar Impulse?

Tags: aircraft-design, solar-impulse

In various images of the Solar Impulse aircraft, I see the engines mounted in different positions along the wing.  Am I looking at SI 1 vs SI 2, or are the mount positions capable of reconfiguration depending on conditions/experimentation?

Comment: Welcome to Aviation. Maybe you can provide URLs to two images showing the difference, that someone will convert in inline images.

Answer (score 6):

**Solar Impulse 1** had 2 engines [right next to the fuselage](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/7471/1696), and the other 2 further out where the wing bends upwards.

[image: Solar Impulse I]

**Solar Impulse 2** has a pair of closely spaced engines on each wing, located partway out onto the wing.

[image: Solar Impulse II]